# Regular expression to replace characters after a specific number of commas

Tags: regex, expression

I have a string like this:

```
word1, word2, word3, word4, word5
```

The result should look like:

```
word1, word2, word3 . . .
```

That is, I would like to replace everything that comes after the third comma (third comma included) with

```
. . .
```

using the Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(([^,]*,){2,2}[^,]*),.*`

and replace it with what is found

`\1 . . .`

I don't have experience with the function but it would probably go like this:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '^(([^,]*,){2,2}[^,]*),.*', '\1 . . .')`

Comment: Thank you! That works! (I only had to take the parentheses off, like this: REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '^(([^,]*,){2,2}[^,]*),.*', '\1 . . .') Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

No need in regular expressions or 'design'.

1. Split on ','
2. iterate and replace.
3. Rejoin and rejoice.

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it only through the Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) instead of regular expression:

```
<?php
$words_to_display = 3;
$str = "word1, word2, word3, word4, word5";

$array = explode(', ', $str);
print_r($array);

$array = array_slice($array, 0, $words_to_display);

$str = implode(', ', $array).' . . .';
echo $str;
?>
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/TTmPhr

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it only through the Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Comment: Humm, not familiar with Oracle. Sorry, skip my answer then. :)